# Blend picture with the color white

Tags: java, colors, blending

```
public class BlendablePicture extends Picture {
    public BlendablePicture(String filename) {
        super(filename);
    }

    public void blendRectWithWhite(int xMin, int yMin, int xMax, int yMax,
            double a) {
        int x;
        x = xMin;
        while (x <= xMax) {
            int y;
            y = yMin;
            while (y <= yMax) {
                Pixel refPix = this.getPixel(x, y);
                refPix.setRed((int) Math.round(refPix.getRed() * (1.0 + a)));
                refPix.setGreen((int) Math.round(refPix.getGreen() * (1.0 + a)));
                refPix.setBlue((int) Math.round(refPix.getBlue() * (1.0 + a)));

                y = y + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to blend the color white with the pixels but instead this code is just making everthing brighter! It needs to look like this:

[image: Blended White - Illustrated]

any help with this code would be appreciated!

Comment: "I need to blend the color white with the pixels but instead this code is just making everthing brighter! "  Um, what?

Comment: the code that I have there under the method "blendRectWithWhite" just intensifies the pixels colors. I need to somehow blend the color white (255,255,255) with an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

`refPix.setRed ( (int) Math.round (refPix.getRed () * (1.0+ a) ));`

Try something like

`refPix.setRed ( (int) Math.round (refPix.getRed()*(1.0-a)+255*a ));`

when a = 1.0, you get R*0.0+255*1.0 = 255

when a = 0.0, you get R*1.0+255*0.0 = R

when a = 0.5, you get R*0.5+255*0.5 (half half)

This works with any colour not just white, you just need to replace the 255 for red, green and blue with the colours of what colour you want to blend with it and you get RGB-averaged blending.

Comment: (Obligatory) Yes, but, will it blend?